# Validate a sample FHIR JSON Bundle Resource with ajv

Tags: json, jsonschema, hl7-fhir, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a [FHIR json Bundle Resource](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lM_95EVwNXs1fbp4wslZ-Y7b38Ek-XZ7) using ajv.

The command line is:

```
ajv validate -s "Bundle.schema.json" -d "SampleBundleDanielToJson.json" -r "*.schema.json"
```

But I get:

```
schema Bundle.schema.json is invalid
error: can't resolve reference Element.schema.json#/definitions/Element from  id http://hl7.org/fhir/json-schema/Element#
```

All FHIR schemas and SampleBundleDanielToJson.json are at the same directory.
I play different options with -r parametres, for example setting referenced schemas one by one but I also do not success.

[FHIR json schemas](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/fhir.schema.json.zip)

Any idea about how to do a FHIR Json validation?
Thanks

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Have you exposed someones home phone number in that FHIR JSON you link to?

Comment: You will need to also provide both schemas to get help here.

Comment: No, it is a sample Json request, data is not real.

Comment: Phew! Just checking! Now you've included the schemas, I'm happy to take a look and see if I can help =]

Comment: Oh man. I think I know what's happening here, but I need more time to check. If I'm right, the JSON Schema files they provide are wrong and problematic at worse... Pretty worrying!

Comment: With JSON Schema draft-4, it does not specify what happens when you use `$ref` at the root leve. draft-5, which as seen as mostly a cleanup / bugfix draft, says all other key words adjacent to `$ref` should be ignored. I guess that might be one of the issues the answer below is referring to.

Comment: You are right, it seems schemas contain some issues. I downloaded the new schemas (http://build.fhir.org/fhir.schema.json.zip) as proposed on Llyod answer and now I am able to validate. Thks.

Answer (score 1):

The FHIR JSON schemas published in FHIR R3 have known issues.  Try using the draft version of FHIR R4 at http://build.fhir.org.

Comment: Thank you so much for you support Lloyd. I downloaded the R4 json schemas and now I am able to validate FHIR sample json files. Now I've to review why my sample is invalid. Regards.

Comment: Obviously that's not a huge help if your data actually needs to be valid against R3.  We just haven't had the bandwidth to be able to go back and update the old release.  (And there are some process challenges around doing that too.)